# Weighted Sum in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take the weighted sum of about 6,500 values with different weights in Excel by using VBA. Here is a simplified example of what I am looking for:

[image: Simplified Example with Sample Data]

I already have Columns A and B and I am looking for the VBA code that can print out what is seen above in Column C under "Weighted Sum". For example, the first "3" printed in the "Weighted Sum" is calculated like this: (5*0.5)+(1*0.5) = 3. I would like to make this dynamic so that I can change the weights (which are currently shown as 50% above).

Comment: Here you're typically expected to at least try to solve your problem before posting, and include your current code in the question (even if it doesn't quite work)

Comment: How about sumproduct?

Comment: Not even a sumproduct, just a freaking `A2*$A$1+B2*$B$1`. You really need to learn the very very basic formulae in Excel.

Comment: @vacip `freaking` I feel I am back in middle school. :) That made me laugh.

Comment: It is a sumproduct!  basic one, but still a sum product.  `=sumproduct($A$1:$B$1,A2:B2)`   If you start getting more than two columns I would think sumproduct is shorter to type in.

Comment: Just to clarify, I do know how to do this as a formula in Excel. The boss needs this in VBA though and I don't really know VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find this helpful. First lesson: not everything in Excel requires VBA, I have created an Excel file with two tabs:

1.) Example - No VBA | Shows how to do this without VBA, one of many approaches

2.) Example - VBA | Shows how to do this with VBA, one of many approaches

*Remember that Alt+F11 opens the editor to view the source code before running any macro*

Working example can be downloaded from here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15166388/StackOverflow/Weighted-Sum-in-VBA/weighted-sum.xlsm

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub WeightedSum()
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : WeightedSum
' Author : vicsar
' Date   : June/13/2016
' Purpose: Teach Basic VBA
' Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799607/weighted-sum-in-vba
' Working example can be downloaded from here:
' https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15166388/StackOverflow/Weighted-Sum-in-VBA/weighted-sum.xlsm
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    On Error GoTo MistHandler

    Dim lngLastRowInExcel As Long
    Dim lngLastRowContainingData As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long


    ' Basic dummy proofing
    ' Check for headers
    If Range("A1").Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find headers. Please review the file and try again", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check for empty columns
    If Range("A2").Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find values in cell A2. Please review the file and try again", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    ' Since the following steps require many screens refreshes using this will make it run fast  You won't be able
    ' to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Defining the last row containign data
    ' Using this approach to make the macro backwards compatile with other versions of Excel
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    lngLastRowInExcel = ActiveCell.Row
    Range("A" & lngLastRowInExcel).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    lngLastRowContainingData = ActiveCell.Row

    Range("A2").Select

    ' Move selection two columns to the right
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select

    ' This loop repeats the formula on every single row adjacent to a value
    For lngCounter = 1 To lngLastRowContainingData - 1
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-2]*0.5)+(RC[-1]*0.5)"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next

    ' Removing formulas, replacing with values (optional)
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

    ' Exit Excel's copy mode
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Go to A1, scroll to it
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.Goto ActiveCell, True

    ' Autofit columns
    Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' Allowing screen updates again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

    ' Error handler
MistHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure WeightedSum of basMain", vbExclamation, " vicsar says"

End Sub
```

Comment: It's quite lot of code like for `Purpose: Teach Basic VBA` ;), but please don't take me wrong - I'm happy with your teaching approach.

Comment: Thanks so much. Appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks to both of you, anytime.

Comment: How can I make it so that the weights are dynamic? Here you have the weights as a part of the code: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-2]*0.5)+(RC[-1]*0.5)". If the weights can be shown as cells that would be great.

Comment: I have updated the code, download the file to see the changes. I am adding a second answer, if it works for you then I would appreciate that you mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another code snippet to answer the follow up question by smathu3. Please read the code comments and adapt as needed.

*How can I make it so that the weights are dynamic? Here you have the weights as a part of the code: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-2]*0.5)+(RC[-1]*0.5)". If the weights can be shown as cells that would be great. – smathu3*

```
Public Sub WeightedSumDynamicWeights()
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : WeightedSumDynamicWeights
' Author : vicsar
' Date   : June/13/2016
' Purpose: Teach Basic VBA
' Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799607/weighted-sum-in-vba
' Working example can be downloaded from here:
' https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15166388/StackOverflow/Weighted-Sum-in-VBA/weighted-sum.xlsm
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    On Error GoTo MistHandler

    Dim lngLastRowInExcel As Long
    Dim lngLastRowContainingData As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    ' Basic dummy proofing
    ' Check for headers
    If Range("A1").Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find headers. Please review the file and try again", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check for empty columns
    If Range("A2").Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find values in cell A2. Please review the file and try again", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    ' Since the following steps require many screens refreshes using this will make it run fast  You won't be able
    ' to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Defining the last row containign data
    ' Using this approach to make the macro backwards compatile with other versions of Excel
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    lngLastRowInExcel = ActiveCell.Row
    Range("A" & lngLastRowInExcel).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    lngLastRowContainingData = ActiveCell.Row

    Range("A2").Select

    ' Move selection two columns to the right
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select

    ' This loop repeats the formula on every single row adjacent to a value
    For lngCounter = 1 To lngLastRowContainingData - 1
        ' Here is the formula, change all instances of Range("F2") to the cell in which you want to store the weight
        ActiveCell.Value = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value * Range("F2")) + (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value * Range("F2"))
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next

    ' Go to A1, scroll to it
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.Goto ActiveCell, True

    ' Autofit columns
    Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' Allowing screen updates again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

    ' Error handler
MistHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure WeightedSumDynamicWeights of basMain", vbExclamation, " vicsar says"

End Sub
```